# Allowiing Jenkins restart from webapp when started from command line

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a windows installation of Jenkins, and I run it as regular logged in user on the desktop via `java -jar jenkins.war`.

Restarting it remotely via the web interface (going to http://jenkins/safeRestart) gives me the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle does not support restart.
```

Is it possible to allow remote restart even when not running as a service?